# Use RegEx to get (parsed) times from string

Tags: php, arrays, regex, time

I need some direction on how to alter my current RegEx line.

Example string:
9:00 AM - 9:30 AM

Desired output:
900 930  (each can be an index in an array or whatever)..

Current approach:

```
preg_match('/^([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2}) ?([ap]m)/i', trim($presentationtime), $matches);
```

however this only seems to get me the FIRST (stripped/parsed) time.

results:

```
$presentationtime = $matches[1] . $matches[2];

echo 'Matches check: '. $matches[0] . '<br>';
echo 'Matches check: '. $matches[1] . '<br>';
```

returns:

Matches check: 9

Matches check: 00

How can I alter my regex to get BOTH times (stripped/parsed the same way)..

I'm expecting a 6 index array..but can only get a 3 index/count array

Comment: Use `preg_match_all`

Comment: Why use regex at all here?  You can simply explode on ` - ` to get the two different time components. You could then take these time components, read them into `DateTime` or similar objects and format output string how ever you want. Is there more complexity in variation of input strings that you are not showing that would suggest regex is a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @anubhava says use preg_match_all

```
$presentationtime = '9:00 AM - 9:30 AM';
preg_match_all('/([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2}) /', trim($presentationtime), $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9:00 
            [1] => 9:30 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 9
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 00
            [1] => 30
        )

)
```

Edit to answer the comment:

very lazy workaround to get one dimensional array, banal regex

```
$presentationtime = '9:00 AM - 9:30 PM';
preg_match('/([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2})\s([apm]+)\s-\s([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2})\s([apm]+)/i', trim($presentationtime), $matches);
```

result

```
Array
(
    [0] => 9:00 AM - 9:30 PM
    [1] => 9
    [2] => 00
    [3] => AM
    [4] => 9
    [5] => 30
    [6] => PM
)
```

Comment: Is there a way to make/grab it all into one (dimensional) array?

My pattern works on REGEX101.com but not in practice..?

An update that was posted is that in fact -do- need the AM/PM stuff as well (to do some 24 hour calculations)

Comment: without regex: 
    `$presentationtime = '9:00 AM - 9:30 PM';
    $stringToDel = array(' ', ':');
    $presentationtime = str_replace($stringToDel, '', $presentationtime);
    $times = explode('-', $presentationtime);
    Array
    (
        [0] => 900AM
        [1] => 930PM
    )`

Answer (score 1):

You have to simply use `preg_match_all` (as stated by anubhava in the comment) and remove the `^` at the start of the regex:

```
preg_match_all('/([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2}) ?([ap]m)/i', trim($presentationtime), $matches);
```

Then `$matches` will be like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9:00 AM
            [1] => 9:30 AM
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 9
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 00
            [1] => 30
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => AM
            [1] => AM
        )

)
```

If you want to refine the regex you may use:

```
preg_match('/([0-9]{1,2}):([0-5]\d)\s*([ap]m)/i', trim($presentationtime), $matches);
```

The minute section is will match 2 digits from 00 to 59, the space section `\s*` is optional and matches more than one whitespace char (space, tab, CR, FF...)

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that:

```
$data = '9:00 AM - 9:30 AM';
print str_replace('-', ' ', preg_replace("/[^0-9-]/","", $data));

Result:
900 930
```

- keep digits and dash
- replace dash with space

In the previous example, I was using limited regex with `preg_replace`. To keep things simple and using time with AM/PM, I'd just explode (as you already thought about),

```
$data = '9:00 AM - 9:30 PM';
$timeArray = array_map('trim', explode('-', $data)); // trim each array item
$timeArray = array_map('Time24Hr', $timeArray); // clean up time
print_r($timeArray);

function Time24Hr($time) {
    $time_ampm = explode(' ', $time);
    if (strtolower(trim($time_ampm[1])) === 'am') {
        // A
        return $time_ampm[0];  
        // B
        //return str_replace(':', '', $time_ampm[0]); 
        // C
        //return $time;
    }

    $hr_min = explode(':', trim($time_ampm[0]));

    // A
    return ($hr_min[0] + 12) . ':' . $hr_min[1];
    // B
    //return ($hr_min[0] + 12) . $hr_min[1];
    // C
    //return ($hr_min[0] + 12) . ':' . $hr_min[1]. ' ' . $time_ampm[1];

}
```

Results:

```
Result A:
Array
(
    [0] => 9:00
    [1] => 21:30
)

Result B:
Array
(
    [0] => 900
    [1] => 2130
)

Result C: -- obviously this is insane, but you can easily make it sane. This is just an example
Array
(
    [0] => 9:00 AM
    [1] => 21:30 PM   
)
```

Of course, this simplistic method can be streamlined much further. This method doesn't need regex.

Comment: I used this:

     ^([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2}) ?([ap]m) (-?) ([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2}) ?([ap]m)

I realized I need to keep the AM/PM to do 24 hour (+12) addition to PM sessions

@zedfoxus that is a nice and clean line of code..  how can I access each time seperately?  (and is there an update to keep the AM/PM with each time?  

Oh.. I just noticed you arent using REGEX..I suppose I could do the same and explode by spaces and replace any : characters.

Comment: @whispers the answer is edited. In my previous answer I used only a little bit of regex in the form of `/[^0-9-]/`. In the edited answer I have avoided the use of regex. I would write this without regex so that it is easier to maintain for someone taking over the code at some point regardless of their experience level.